# Got garbage when getting shader compile log

Tags: opengl, shaders

I got garbage when trying to compile shader and get error log. I checked my code against some sample code, and could figure out where I did wrong.

Below is my code:

```
bool LoadShader(GLuint ShaderType, char const* ShaderFileName)
{
    os_file ShaderFile = OSReadFile(ShaderFileName);
    GLint ShaderHandle = glCreateShader(ShaderType);
    DebugPrint("Shader source: %s\n%.*s\n", ShaderFileName, ShaderFile.Length, ShaderFile.Contents);

    GLchar* ShaderSource = (GLchar*)&ShaderFile.Contents;
    GLint ShaderSourceLength = ShaderFile.Length;
    glShaderSource(ShaderHandle, 1, &ShaderSource, &ShaderSourceLength);
    glCompileShader(ShaderHandle);

    OSFreeFile(&ShaderFile);

    GLint Success;
    glGetShaderiv(ShaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Success);
    if (!Success)
    {
        GLchar CompileLog[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderType, 512, NULL, CompileLog);
        switch (ShaderType)
        {
#define SHADER_TYPE_ERROR(ShaderType) case ShaderType: { DebugPrint(#ShaderType " Compile error!\n"); } break;
            SHADER_TYPE_ERROR(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            SHADER_TYPE_ERROR(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
#undef SHADER_TYPE_ERROR
        }
        DebugPrint("%s\n\n", CompileLog);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Below is some output:

```
Shader source: shader/fragment.glsl
#version 330 core

out vec4 Colour;

void main()
{
    Colour = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
}


GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER Compile error!
p��R�
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderType, 512, NULL, CompileLog);
```

To

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderHandle, 512, NULL, CompileLog);
```

Also consider using

```
GLint len = 0;
glGetShaderiv(ShaderHandle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);
```

and allocating your text buffer using `len`.

Comment: Nice catch!!!!!! I hope I can delete this question, it's a stupid bug

Comment: You can leave it, someone else might hit the same issue.